# Running Multiple Python Versions

Tags: python, multiple-versions

I want to run multiple Python versions in my box. Is there any version manager for Python where I can switch between multiple Python versions without having to call the full path of the Python binary? I have tried `virtualenv` and it seems to only cover problems running multiple Python library versions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually this is handled by your operating system shell.  What are operating system and/or shell are you using?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am using Ubuntu and bash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use virtualenv to keep track of different environments I need for my projects. I may setup django 1.0 in one environment or django 1.2 for another. You can use it to set which version of python you'd like to use in a particular environment as well. Here's the link to the site which has great samples and tutorials for how to get running: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Answer (score 10):

When calling python from bash you could try an alias.

```
user@machine:~$ alias python1234='/usr/bin/python2.5'
user@machine:~$ python1234
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Jan 20 2010, 21:44:03) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Let's say you have a script called script.py with following content:

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

So, launching a script with a different version of python looks like:

```
user@machine:~$ python script.py 
2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41) 
[GCC 4.3.3]
user@machine:~$ python1234 script.py 
2.5.4 (r254:67916, Jan 20 2010, 21:44:03) 
[GCC 4.3.3]
```

Comment: This might make sense for self-compiled pythons in weird locations such as /opt/my-python2.7/bin/python, but I don't see the point for Ubuntu-provided python2.5, which you can already call by a short name: 'python2.5'.

Comment: The above case of self-compiled pythons in /opt/python2.7 was exactly what I needed this for, so it is very helpful for that.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use the full path.

```
user@machine:$ python2.5
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Sep 14 2010, 17:16:34) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

user@machine:$ python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Also, if you wanted just to type in `python` to run your version of choice at the moment, all that `python` is, is a symbolic link to `python2.5`, `python2.6`, etc., so you could make a link to those binaries in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score -1):

## Installing Multiple Interpreter Versions

`node-build` is a common tool for *installing* multiple Node versions.

`node-build` installation:

```bash
brew install node-build
```

`node-build` usage:

```bash
node-build 14.20.1 ~/.nodes/node-14.20.1
node-build 16.17.1 ~/.nodes/node-16.17.1
```

`python-build` is a common tool for *installing* multiple Python versions.

`python-build` installation:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git
cd pyenv/plugins/python-build
./install.sh
```

`python-build` usage:

```bash
python-build 3.8.10 ~/.pythons/python-3.8.10
python-build 3.9.13 ~/.pythons/python-3.9.13
```

## Managing Multiple Interpreter Versions

`rvm`, `rbenv`, and `chruby` are common tools for *managing* multiple Ruby versions. They inspired `nvm`, `nodenv`, and `chnode` which are equivalent tools for *managing* multiple Node versions. They also inspired `pyenv` and `chpython` which are equivalent tools for *managing* multiple Python versions (there is no `rvm` equivalent as far as I know).

To automatically switch the targeted executables located in the `bin` directories of the installed Ruby versions when invoking a Ruby command (`ruby`, `irb`, `rake`, `gem`, …) based on the Ruby version defined in the .ruby-version file of the current or nearest parent directory, the tools use different strategies (from the heaviest to the lightest):

- `rvm` updates the `PATH` environment variable before each invocation of the `cd` command by redefining the `cd` command;
- `rbenv` invokes the Ruby command in a dedicated environment with an updated `PATH` environment variable by executing a proxy executable ([*shim*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422296/2326961));
- `chruby` updates the `PATH` environment variable before each invocation of a command by executing a function hooked into the shell with `preexec_functions` for Zsh and `PROMPT_COMMAND` for Bash.

The drawback of the `rvm` strategy is that it is invasive and slow. The drawback of the `rbenv` strategy is that it is complex and requires shims to be regenerated (*rehashed*) at each installation of a Ruby version or Ruby package (*gem*) that provides an executable. The `chruby` strategy does not have those issues so `chruby` is the recommended tool.

`chnode` installation:

```bash
brew tap tkareine/chnode
brew install tkareine/chnode/chnode
echo "source /usr/local/opt/chnode/share/chnode/chnode.sh" >>~/.zshrc
echo "source /usr/local/opt/chnode/share/chnode/auto.sh" >>~/.zshrc
echo "precmd_functions+=(chnode_auto)" >>~/.zshrc
```

`chnode` usage:

```bash
echo $PATH
# /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
chnode
#    node-14.20.1
#    node-16.17.1
chnode 16.17.1
echo $PATH
# /Users/me/.nodes/node-16.17.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
chnode
#    node-14.20.1
#  * node-16.17.1
echo 14.20.1 >.node-version
echo $PATH
# /Users/me/.nodes/node-14.20.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
chnode
#  * node-14.20.1
#    node-16.17.1
```

`chpython` installation:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/kisoku/chpython.git
cd chpython
make install
echo "source /usr/local/share/chpython/chpython.sh" >>~/.zshrc
echo "source /usr/local/share/chpython/auto.sh" >>~/.zshrc
```

`chpython` usage:

```bash
echo $PATH
# /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
chpython
#    python-3.8.10
#    python-3.9.13
chpython 3.9.13
echo $PATH
# /Users/me/.pythons/python-3.9.13/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
chpython
#    python-3.8.10
#  * python-3.9.13
echo 3.8.10 >.python-version
echo $PATH
# /Users/me/.pythons/python-3.8.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
chpython
#  * python-3.8.10
#    python-3.9.13
```