# How do RVM and rbenv actually work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, rbenv

I am interested in how RVM and rbenv actually work.

Obviously they swap between different versions of Ruby and gemsets, but how is this achieved? I had assumed they were simply updating symlinks, but having delved into the code (and I must admit my knowledge of Bash is superficial) they appear to be doing more than this.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Short explanation: rbenv works by hooking into your environment's `PATH`. The concept is simple, but the devil is in the details; full scoop below.

First, rbenv creates *shims* for all the commands (`ruby`, `irb`, `rake`, `gem` and so on) across all your installed versions of Ruby, that is for all files in `~/.rbenv/versions/*/bin`. This process is called *rehashing*. Every time you install a new version of Ruby or install a gem that provides a command, run `rbenv rehash` to make sure any new commands are shimmed.

These shims live in a single directory (`~/.rbenv/shims` by default). To use rbenv, you need only add the shims directory to the front of your `PATH`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
```

Then any time you run `ruby` from the command line, or run a script whose shebang reads `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, your operating system will find `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby` first and run it instead of any other `ruby` executable you may have installed.

Each shim is a tiny Bash script that in turn runs `rbenv exec`. So with rbenv in your path, `irb` is equivalent to `rbenv exec irb`, and `ruby -e "puts 42"` is equivalent to `rbenv exec ruby -e "puts 42"`.

The `rbenv exec` command figures out what version of Ruby you want to use, then runs the corresponding command for that version. Here's how:

1. If the `RBENV_VERSION` environment variable is set, its value determines the version of Ruby to use.
2. If the current working directory has an `.rbenv-version` file, its contents are used to set the `RBENV_VERSION` environment variable.
3. If there is no `.rbenv-version` file in the current directory, rbenv searches each parent directory for an `.rbenv-version` file until it hits the root of your filesystem. If one is found, its contents are used to set the `RBENV_VERSION` environment variable.
4. If `RBENV_VERSION` is still not set, rbenv tries to set it using the contents of the `~/.rbenv/version` file.
5. If no version is specified anywhere, rbenv assumes you want to use the "system" Ruby—i.e. whatever version would be run if rbenv weren't in your path.

(You can set a project-specific Ruby version with the `rbenv local` command, which creates a `.rbenv-version` file in the current directory. Similarly, the `rbenv global` command modifies the `~/.rbenv/version` file.)

Armed with an `RBENV_VERSION` environment variable, rbenv adds `~/.rbenv/versions/$RBENV_VERSION/bin` to the front of your `PATH`, then execs the command and arguments passed to `rbenv exec`. Voila!

For a thorough look at exactly what happens under the hood, try setting `RBENV_DEBUG=1` and running a Ruby command. Every Bash command that rbenv runs will be written to your terminal.

---

Now, rbenv is just concerned with switching versions, but a thriving ecosystem of plugins will help you do everything from [installing Ruby](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) to [setting up your environment](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars), [managing "gemsets"](https://github.com/jamis/rbenv-gemset) and even [automating `bundle exec`](https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler).

I am not quite sure what IRC support has to do with switching Ruby versions, and rbenv is designed to be simple and understandable enough not to require support. But should you ever need help, the issue tracker and Twitter are just a couple of clicks away.

*Disclosure: I am the author of rbenv, ruby-build, and rbenv-vars.*

Answer (score 19):

I wrote an in-depth article: http://niczsoft.com/2011/11/what-you-should-know-about-rbenv-and-rvm/

The basic difference is where the shell environment is changed:

- RVM: it's changed when you change Ruby.
- rbenv: it's changed when you run a Ruby/gem executable.

Also, the thing about RVM is, it covers a lot more then just managing Rubies, it has a lot more than any other tool (there are others apart from RVM and rbenv: https://twitter.com/#!/mpapis/status/171714447910502401)

Do not forget about instant support you get on IRC in the "#rvm" channel on the Freenode servers.

Answer (score 16):

So to summarise the excellent answers above, the main practical difference between RVM and rbenv is when the version of Ruby is selected.

**rbenv:**

rbenv adds a shim to the start of your path, a command with the same name as Ruby. When you type `ruby` at a command line the shim is run instead (because it is also called "ruby" and comes first in the path). The shim looks for an environment variable or `.rbenv_version` file to tell it which version of Ruby to delegate to.

**RVM:**

RVM allows you to set a version of Ruby directly by calling `rvm use`. In addition, it also overrides the `cd` system command. When you `cd` into a folder that contains a `.rvmrc` file, the code inside the `.rvmrc` file is executed. This can be used to set a Ruby version, or anything else you fancy.

**Other differences:**

There are of course other differences. RVM has gemsets out of the box, while rbenv requires just a little more hacking (but not much). Both are functional solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference seems to be [when and how ruby is switched](http://niczsoft.com/2011/11/what-you-should-know-about-rbenv-and-rvm/). Ruby is switched:

- for RVM manually (rvm use) or automatically during change of directories
- for rbenv automatically each time a ruby command is executed

RVM relies on the modified `cd` command and manual selection of Ruby by `rvm use`. rbenv uses wrappers or "shims" for all basic ruby commands as the default mechanism to select ruby. RVM creates wrappers for basic command line tools like gem, rake, ruby, too. They are used for example in CronJobs ( see http://rvm.io/integration/cron/ ), but they are not the default mechanism to switch the Ruby version.

Thus both methods select "automatically" the right Ruby version by overwriting commands and using wrappers. rvm overrides shell commands like cd. rbenv overrides all basic ruby commands such as ruby, irb, rake and gem.

Answer (score 6):

```
rvm system
env > before
rvm jruby # or whatever
env > after
diff after before
```

Gives you approximately:

```
< GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
---
> GEM_HOME=$HOME/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6
< GEM_PATH=$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
---
> GEM_PATH=$HOME/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6:$HOME/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@global
*bunch of rvm_*
> MY_RUBY_HOME=$HOME/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6
> RUBY_VERSION=jruby-1.6.6
> IRBRC=$HOME/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6/.irbrc
```

And it prepends:

```
$HOME/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6/bin:$HOME/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@global/bin
```

to `$PATH`