# Permission Error When Trying To Install Rails (OSX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, permissions

I am new to programming and am trying to get rails installed on my terminal. I have been following instructions from a friend, installing the xcode command line tools, homebrew, git, rbenv, ruby-build, ruby gems, ruby, and postgres. But whenever, I try $gem install rails, I get the following:

```
Russell-Silvers-MacBook-Pro:~ Russell_Silver$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Russell_Silver/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/README.md
```

This is especially frustrating because when I run $gem list, it says I have rails 3.2.18. Which is peculiar, because when I run $rails v$, it tells me I have Rails 4.2.0.

When I try to use rails `rails my new_app`

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Russell_Silver/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/README.md
An error occurred while installing rails (4.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rails -v '4.2.0'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/Users/Russell_Silver/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:83: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/Russell_Silver in PATH, mode 040707
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
Russell-Silvers-MacBook-Pro:~ Russell_Silver$ bundle install
/Users/Russell_Silver/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb:355: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/Russell_Silver in PATH, mode 040707
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

This is really frustrating, especially for someone new to programming such as myself, so I am seeking help from anybody who might know what is wrong.

Comment: How did you install `rbenv`? If you used `sudo` with the installation, this may be expected behavior.

Comment: I used HomeBrew
$brew install rbenv

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You could try `sudo chown -R Russell_Silver ~/.rbenv`. This will take ownership of the directory.

Comment: You're a legend! It worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem. Turned this to an answer so that later folk can refer to it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your `rbenv` installation was incorrectly installed as it had elevated privileges which caused your user account to not have write access to `~/.rbenv`.

Issue the following command in order to take of ownership of the directory:

```
 sudo chown -R Russell_Silver ~/.rbenv
```

Note that some users may have a different `rbenv` directory, e.g. `/usr/local/var/rbenv`. This would take the place of `~/.rbenv` in the above command.

Comment: I had the same issue. Running the above command fixed it. Thanks a lot!