# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied in create new app ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

After install fresh ruby (v 2.2.2) and rails (v 4.2.1). i try create  new app by commnad `rails new app` in my terminal.
But print errors like this:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/byebug-5.0.0
An error occurred while installing byebug (5.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '5.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After that i run `bundle install` . but again show same error!
how to fixed this issue? Why it say  **Permission denied** ?

Thanks.

Comment: necessary permissions must be provided to folder in above path, use `chmod` cmd.

Comment: @Nithin Which folder?

Comment: `debug` yourself, or you can provide recursively for that structure.

Comment: @Nithin  I did not understand ! Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem

Answer (score 1):

Try installing gem `byebug` with sudo privilege

```
sudo gem install byebug -v '5.0.0'
```

Enter the password to elevate the privilege. 

Perhaps this would solve this issue temporarily, consider looking at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem)

Comment: This worked for me by just doing `sudo bundle install` now it did give me an error: `Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.` but i am the only user so i don't care.