# rubygems-update error when I run gem update --system

Tags: macos, rubygems

When I run `gem update --system` in MacOS Sierra, I have a problem like this:

```
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.10
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/doc/rubygems-update-2.6.10
```

Comment: Where's the code that generates this problem?

Comment: I've got the same problem, it's just `gem update --system`.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem - try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem