# libxml issue when installing twilio-ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, libxml2

I've been running in circles trying to install the 'twilio-ruby' gem in my rails app to no avail. Every time I try to bundle install I receive errors around libxml. Below is a part of the error I'm receiving when I add 'twilio-ruby' to the gem-file and try to bundle install:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/HISTORY
An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (3.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Trying to gem install libxml-ruby results in the error below:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/HISTORY
```

Any help that points me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: did y try `gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0` and please include the result of that command

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio: I've tried that and this is the error I'm receiving: `code`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/HISTORY`code`

Answer (score 2):

to install correctly `rbenv` follow the instructions on github for your operating system (Mac or Linux)

[rbenv installation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation)

While to better understand this problem, it is connected to security issues. Mac and Linux are Unix based system, where the user logs in and can execute commands on his home directory `~/<user>`. If you try to execute a command to run a script in another directory like the root directory `/` or `/bin`, you will get an authorization error and you will need to run the command with `sudo` that stands for `system user do`.

For this reason, with linux you configure the `~/.bash_profile` file

> Add ~/.rbenv/bin to your $PATH for access to the rbenv command-line utility.
>
> $ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
>   Ubuntu Desktop note: Modify your ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile.
>
> Zsh note: Modify your ~/.zshrc file instead of ~/.bash_profile.

so that those command `irb`, `gem`, `rake`, `rails` when executed from the user they:

> - Search your PATH for an executable file named rake
> - Find the rbenv shim named rake at the beginning of your PATH
> - Run the shim named rake, which in turn passes the command along to rbenv

[explanation of shims in rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#understanding-shims)

You can also solve easily this problem by running the command with `sudo`, but it is not reccommended, as you can read also from the below post where they have the same problem but with `rvm`,

[Why do I get a "permission denied" error while installing a gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I will work on installing rbenv on my mac tonight. In the meantime, I just wanted to point out that I did try running the installation with sudo and this is a portion of the error which it returns: `Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.`

Comment: @GeorgeMikhail you should locate `mkmf.log` and see what is the problem. Anyway you should not use `sudo`.  `mkmf.log` should be saved somewhere inside the folders of `/Users/George/.rbenv`..