# Cannot launch cloned ruby on rails app - RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have cloned an existing project from github. I installed Ruby and installed Rails on my Terminal.

When I do `ruby -v` I get `ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]`

When I do `rails -v` I get `Rails 6.0.3.1`

However when I navigate into my project that I want to run on local host and run the same commands:

for `ruby -v` I get `ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]` which is the same.

and for `rails -v` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    2: from /Users/angelainniss/WebstormProjects/legitkitchen/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/angelainniss/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/angelainniss/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

Has anyone ever had this or do they understand why `rails` isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `rails` command is pretty smart and it knows it will be usually called within the rails project folder. So it have its binstubs - basically those are just a slightly modified commands that lives in your project `bin` folder, with some additional, project-related power-ups. Regular `rails` command (and other commands as well) will always check if `bin/rails` is present in current directory and will use it if it exists. This is why `rails -v` worked fine outside of your project but didn't inside project folder.

One of the `bin/rails` superpowers is automatic requiring of all dependencies defined in your project Gemfile. This is normally done through another gem called `bundler`. Bundler is basically always the first gem you're gona install in your local Ruby environment.

But, you didn't install it yet. Just run `gem install bundler` to get that running. You will still need to install all the dependencies, you do this via `bundle install`.

Comment: I tried this @BroiSatse but i get another error when I do `gem install bundler`. error message is this: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/angelainniss/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/CHANGELOG.md
` Any ideas why

Comment: @AngelaInniss - This is now another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem

Answer (score 0):

Did you do, `gem install bundler` before running `bundle install` after cloning the project?